# $S^{3}$-valued harmonic analysis

Tags: gn.general-topology, oa.operator-algebras, harmonic-analysis, geometric-group-theory, noncommutative-geometry

**Edit:**

Note  that $S^{3}$  with the quaternion operation is  a  group. For  a  locally  compact  Abelian group $\Gamma$ we consider
$$\tilde{\tilde{\Gamma}}=\{\phi:\Gamma \to S^{3} \mid  \phi(xy)=\phi(x)\phi(y) \}$$
This  is  the $S^{3}$  valued analogue of
$$\tilde{\Gamma}=\{\phi:\Gamma\to S^{1}\mid\phi(xy)=\phi(x)\phi(y)\}$$

**As nsrt  pointed out in his comment** this  is not more than an  space(not necessarily a group).We equip  space with compact open topology. It seems that one can prove that $\tilde{\tilde{\Gamma}}$ is  compact(discrete) if $\Gamma$ is discrete(compact).

> 1. Does  $\tilde{\tilde {\Gamma}}$  have a  known  topological structure  for  $\Gamma=\mathbb{Z}$  or  $\Gamma=S^{1}$. (Is it  homeomorphic  to  a  known topological space?)
>
> 2.Motivated by Pontryagin theorem  for  $S^{1}$ valued harmonic  analysis, we  ask: Is it true that This  topological space is  connected $\iff$ $\Gamma$  is  torsion free.
>
> 3.We know  that $C_{red}^{*} \Gamma$  is  an operator theoretical version of $C(\tilde{\Gamma})$. Now we ask: What is  a non commutative( and operator theoretical)  analogues of $C(\tilde{\tilde{\Gamma}})$?

Comment: This isn't enough for a full answer, but it seems straightforward that for $\Gamma=\mathbb Z$, the space $\tilde{\tilde{\Gamma}}$ is just $S^3$ again, by the same proof as in the classical case of $S^1$ (since $\mathbb Z$ is cyclic and generated by $1$, the "character" $\phi$ determines (and is determined by) the value $\phi(1)\in S^3$, so we get a bijection, which is continuous by the definition of the topology, and hence a homeomorphism by virtue of compactness.)

Comment: @MikeJury  yes thank you. About $\tilde{\tilde{S^{1}}}$ one can find, at least 3 copy of $\mathbb{Z}$ in it. But how they match to each other?

Comment: Isn't it more complicated than that? If we choose real numbers $b,c,d$ satisfying $b^2+c^2+d^2=1$ and form the quaternion $q=bi+cj+dk$, then $q^2=-1$, and $\phi(x+iy)=x+yq$ is homomorphism of $S^1$ into $S^3$?

Comment: How is homomorphisms into $S^3$ a group? I only see a topological space. You need commutativity of $S^1$ for the Pontryagin dual group structure.

Comment: @nsrt  Yes. Thank you for your comment. I was incorrect. The pointwise multiplication does not give us  a  group structure since $S^{3}$ is  not  abelian. I revise the question

Comment: Continuous group homomorphisms from $S^1$ to a Lie group are automatically smooth (this is related to Hilbert's fifth problem, and I think was proved by Brouwer), so indeed @MikeJury wrote down all injective group homomorphisms $S^1\to S^3$, and this space is homeomorphic to $S^2$. The space of all group homomorphisms is now obtained by composing with all group homomorphisms $S^1\to S^1$. So the space we obtain is the union of a point and a countable union of copies of $S^2$.